# How is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality used in the proof of Lyapunov's criterion in the book "Analysis and Geometry of Markov Diffusion Operators"

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $(E,\mu,\Gamma)$ be a *full Markov triple* (see definition below), $J\in\mathcal A$ with $J\ge1$ and $g\in\mathcal A_0$. In the proof of Theorem 4.6.2 of the book ["Analysis and Geometry of Markov Diffusion Operators"](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319002262), it's claimed that $$\Gamma\left(\frac{g^2}J,J\right)=\frac{2g}J\Gamma(g,J)-\frac{g^2}{J^2}\Gamma(J)\le\Gamma(g)\tag1.$$ The authors claim that the equality holds by the diffusion property of $\Gamma$, while the second inequality holds by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for $\Gamma$ (which states that ${\Gamma(f,h)}^2\le\Gamma(f)\Gamma(h)$.

> I don't get how the inequality follows by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Could anybody explain this to me?

[image: full Markov triple]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a:=\frac gJ$, $b:=\sqrt{\Gamma(J)}$, $c:=\sqrt{\Gamma(g)}$. By Cauchy--Schwarz, $\Gamma(g,J)\le bc$. So, the inequality in question reduces to $2abc-a^2b^2\le c^2$, or to the obvious inequality $(ab-c)^2\ge0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've got a related question: If $f\in\mathcal A_0$ and $m:=\int_K f\:{\rm d}\mu$ for some measurable $K\subseteq E$. Is $\frac{LJ}J|f-m|^2$ integrable (or nonnegative and hence quasi-integrable) wrt $\mu$? I don't see this.

Comment: I think, once your original question is answered, it is better to ask any further questions in separate posts.